# How do I get rid of TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float in read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse 2 columns, 1 and 2, into a datetime while I also read column 6 and 12 of a csv file. The code is as follows. For some reason I am getting the following error:

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float

```
date_parse = lambda d,t: datetime.strptime(
                                           d+t,
                                           "%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S"
                                           )


data_frame = pd.read_csv(
              full_path_file_name, sep=";",
              header=0,
              usecols=[1, 2, 6, 12],
              skiprows=6,
              parse_dates={'datetime': ['Date','Time']},
              date_parser=date_parse
              )
```

Does anyone have any suggestion to get rid of this error?

You can check the [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMQnA.png)
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to add a print to your lambda function so you can see which line of the csv produces the error, then post that line.

Comment: How do I add a print statement there? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: why have you written d,t in lambda function?

Comment: d stands for date and t stands for time
I wrote d and t because date and time are in two different columns: column #1 and column #2 of the csv file.

Comment: Please add what your dataset looks like also

Comment: Please delete your lambda function and add this to your code : `def date_parse(d, t): print(d, t); return datetime.strptime(d+t, "%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: And post the output of your program with that

Comment: I just added a link to the picture of the dataset on my first message.

Comment: Output of print(d,t) as follows:['28/06/2018' '28/06/2018' '28/06/2018' ... '07/05/2018' '07/05/2018'
 '07/05/2018'] ['12:38:36' '12:35:38' '12:21:39' ... '17:14:00' '17:09:00' '17:04:00']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```py
                                    )
def date_parse(d, t):
    dt = d+ " " +t
    return pd.to_datetime(dt)


data_frame = pd.read_csv(
              full_path_file_name, sep=";",
              header=0,
              usecols=[1, 2, 6, 12],
              skiprows=6,
              parse_dates={'datetime': ['Date','Time']},
              date_parser=date_parse
              )
```

Comment: One thing that I did not understand is that use of that `usecols`. When there are only 2 column in your dataset, why have you used unncessary columns? use `usecols=['Date','Time']`

Comment: This is the output I get if I do it as you suggested: HelloTypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Answer for: "When there are only 2 column in your dataset, why have you used unncessary columns?"---->I also have data on columns 6 and 12 but I thought it is not relevant for this question. Anyway, I just replaced usecols=[1, 2, 6, 12] with usecols=['Date','Time'] and I got the same output: TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @goahead97 then can you show what d+t result actually is?

Comment: d+t
array(['28/06/201812:38:36', '28/06/201812:35:38', '28/06/201812:21:39',
       ..., '07/05/201817:14:00', '07/05/201817:09:00',
       '07/05/201817:04:00'], dtype=object)

d
array(['28/06/2018', '28/06/2018', '28/06/2018', ..., '07/05/2018',
       '07/05/2018', '07/05/2018'], dtype=object)

Comment: d
array(['28/06/2018', '28/06/2018', '28/06/2018', ..., '07/05/2018',
       '07/05/2018', '07/05/2018'], dtype=object)

Comment: t
array(['12:38:36', '12:35:38', '12:21:39', ..., '17:14:00', '17:09:00',
       '17:04:00'], dtype=object)

Comment: @goahead97 updated my answer, you are missing space between data and time

Comment: @goahead97 has the above solution fixed your problem?

Comment: I do not think there is a need to include a space there (d+" "+t) because the pattern "%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S" does not have any space in between date and time.